# Grid view state problem?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have created a simple grid which shows different images with an edit option. The user selects the drop down to view `png` or `jpg` images. If `jpg` is selected, the user is redirected to a Silverlight application to edit the image. When the user goes back to the default page, the `png` option is selected by default. I would want that the selection of `jpg` is remembered.

How can we maintain the state of the application, so that when the user goes back, the selected image type is remembered and the grid shows the data of the selected type? It is in asp.net C#

Comment: you can pass in the rowindex and dropdown selection as parameters of querystring to and fro

Comment: add rowindex to session and when go back read from session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it in session:

```
Session["ImageSelector"] = cbImageSelector.SelectedIndex
```

And in Page_Load, when !Page.IsPostback, check:

```
object key = Session["ImageSelector"];
if (key != null)
    this.cbImageSelector.SelectedIndex = (int)key;
```

You could also use a cookie too, via Response.Cookies and get it via Request.Cookies.

HTH.